# PHP loop over array and fill out missing values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object that looks like this: (`$city`)

```
MyClass^ {#7659
  +fr: "Londres"
  +en: "London"
  +de: null
}
```

So basically it's the translation of a city in multiple locales

Now my goals is to fill out the missing locales with the first locale that is available.

Here's what I am trying:

```
$result = [];
foreach (['fr', 'en', 'de'] as $locale) {
    if (is_string($city->$locale)) {
        $result[$locale] = $city->$locale;
    }
}
```

But this returns:

```
[
  "fr" => "Londres",
  "en" => "London"
]
```

My goals is this:

```
[
  "fr" => "Londres",
  "en" => "London",
  "de" => "Londres"
]
```

Comment: Careful: you've missed a single quote in `'fr', 'en, 'de'`.

Comment: What is your rule for in this case setting the missing German translation to the French one? You just pick the first one?

Comment: It doesn't appear to make logical sense to arbitrarily put the name from one language into another language. How does that help anyone? Once you've done that, you've got a big pile of incorrect translations instead of a big pile of missing translations. That's a) still not very useful, and b) a lot harder to detect.

Comment: @RoAchterberg yes the first available translation so in this case the fr one

Comment: @ADyson it's for sorting purpose, i can't sort on null values

Comment: Sure you can. What is your intended sorted output?

Comment: @michael maybe use empty strings, then. Or, better, adjust your sorting algorithm to cope - it should be possible.

Comment: I need a translation in there it cannot be an empty string or null or anything unfortunately

Comment: Why not? The value shouldn't matter. This sounds like an X-Y problem, where it seems the real issue is probably a bug in your sorting code. (At the worst, if for some bizarre reason null or empty strings aren't an option, you'd be better to put something like "ZZZZ" in them all, instead of a word from a different language. Then at least later on you could still easily see where there are translations missing. But really...just fix your sorting algorithm, and/or go and find some real data to put in there.)

Comment: How about actually finding all the proper translations?

Comment: While I think your logic provides a poor UX, I've provided a solution that answers your business logic. It is scalable and somewhat efficient. But surely you should instead be setting the empty values to the most common language used!

Comment: Additionally, your design of setting a public variable for every locale could use some work. How about using an array at least? The variable names are very non-descriptive because of the ambiguous two-letter abbreviations.

Comment: This is not what one does. One does not statically store fallback values. Instead you use getter methods to access the properties (here translations). And the getter implement a fallback language or strategy. That way you do not generate stale data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way that is relatively efficient. Handles first and/or multiple `NULL`s. See comments for explanation.

```
<?php

class City
{
    public ?string $de = NULL;
    public ?string $fr = 'Londres';
    public string $en = 'London';
}

$city = new City;

$result = [];
// Helper lookup array to keep track of all the NULL locales.
$nullIndices = [];
// Loop over each locale and fill the result.
foreach (['fr', 'de', 'en'] as $iso6391)
{
    // Got a NULL value? Record its key so we can fill it
    // once we have a first value.
    if ($city->$iso6391 === NULL)
        $nullIndices[] = $iso6391;
    else
    {
        // Got an actual result (not a placeholder), store it now.
        $result[$iso6391] = $city->$iso6391;
        
        // Set a first value only once.
        $firstValue = $firstValue??$result[$iso6391];
        
        // For any accumulated NULL values, set them now to the first value.
        // Remove the keys once they've been set to the placeholder.
        foreach ($nullIndices as $nullIndex)
        {
            $result[$nullIndex] = $firstValue;
            unset($nullIndices[$nullIndex]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
/*
array(3) {
  ["fr"]=>
  string(7) "Londres"
  ["en"]=>
  string(6) "London"
  ["de"]=>
  string(7) "Londres"
}
*/
```